# jQuery vs AngularJS - which is good for big projects?`

Tags: jquery, angularjs

For a big project I must use JavaScript, and I can not choose what is good for my project. For example, my project has a Facebook and [Google+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google%2B) transaction. jQuery is very simple and AngularJS can use MVC. For a BIF project, what's good and has the best performance?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. JQuery is an extensible library of useful DOM manipulating functions; AngularJS is an application framework. Apples and oranges.

Comment: Would you really starting a big project just following some random dudes opinion? You should start to learn angularjs and see if that fits your needs, or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery handles your DOM (document object module) and its elements better. If your choice is not to include the [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations; then I say you better walk away swift with jQuery and otherwise (with CRUD operation) use AngularJS.

The purpose of spacifying DOM is that you can make fluid changes with the loaded data on the browser's part. Mostly, if you see scripting error that's because the DOM is not read/understood properly while working with jQuery.

**AngularJS is basically a **build tool/framework** that does awesome work
including:**

- Twoway data binding
- MVW pattern (MVC-ish)
- Template
- Custom-directive (reusable components, custom markup)
- [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)-friendly
- Deep Linking (set up a link for any dynamic page)
- Form validation
- Server communication
- Localization
- [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)
- Full testing environment (both unit, e2e)

jQuery has its own characteristics:

- Data-binding
- jQuery is lean and mean
- Seamlessly handles crossbrowser issues
- jQuery uses a simple, clean, powerful syntax
- jQuery is highly extensible
- jQuery will receive active development support for years to come
- Best you have come from a JavaScript background.
- [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) support
- DOM Manipulation

Answer (score 1):

Check here for an amazing write-up on the key differences between jQuery and AngularJS. It should give you some really useful tips on the tradeoffs:

["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)